# Magento 1 Source Model similar to favicon

Tags: magento-1.9, module, source-model

I've developed a module where it allows clients to upload a single image via the `adminhtml/system_config_backend_image_favicon` which I've overridden. In what other way would you guys implement this?

But i was wondering if there is another way that magento provides to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the source model `Mage_Adminhtml_Model_System_Config_Backend_Image` (`adminhtml/system_config_backend_image`).
take a look at how `logo_html` field is added in `system.xml` from the Sales module.